# How to Count Rows And Set a Number For Each Item

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, postgresql-9.5

I need to retrieve a collection from the database and count each line, the amount of rows is not important to me, I need to set a number for each record.

I'm doing something like this:

```
var items = await Context.MyModelTable.AsNoTracking().
     Select(tbl => new 
{
   Code = tbl.Code,
   Name = tbl.Name,
   Row = ???
})
.ToListAsync();
```

If the anonymous list has 3 items, the first Item must receive 1, the second 2 and thyrd 3.

I know I could do it with a loop after bring the collection from database, but if I do like this I will not be able to use Anonymous type.

Is there any way to do it directly from database?

I'm using Entity Framework Core with Postgresql

Comment: Maybe something like: `Select((tbl, i) => new 
{
   Code = tbl.Code,
   Name = tbl.Name,
   Row = i
})`

Comment: Hi Zaggler, after doing this I get the error: 
The LINQ expression could not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to 'AsEnumerable', 'AsAsyncEnumerable', 'ToList', or 'ToListAsync'.
If I run withou 'i' no errors are returned

Answer (score 0):

```
var items = await Context.MyModelTable.AsNoTracking().Select((tbl, index) => new 
{
   Code = tbl.Code,
   Name = tbl.Name,
   Row = index
})
.ToListAsync();
```

`Select` can also take an `index` argument giving you an index (int).

This code assumes `Row` is an int, you haven't shown us the type so it's an assumption.

Comment: Hi Jaymee, after doing this I get the error: 
The LINQ expression could not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to 'AsEnumerable', 'AsAsyncEnumerable', 'ToList', or 'ToListAsync'.
If I run withou index no errors are returned